# SQL to insert text & combine another column's data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table called `TEMP` and two columns `[col1]` and `[col2]`

`[col1]` has a list of names. `[col2]` is currently empty.

I am trying to insert into `[col2]` some text with special characters and include the name from `[col1]` in each insert.

So basically in `[col2]` I want (special characters included as well):

```
some text < " > [col1] < " > some text
```

BTW I'm using SQL Server 2012 in case that makes a difference in the SQL.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `'some text' + col1 + 'some more text'`.

Comment: @Andrew: not in SQL Server

Comment: Gah, forgot that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update TEMP 
set col2 = 'some text < " >' + [col1] + '< " > some text'
```

Comment: ah easier that I thought.

Thanks!